# Is it legal to change __stack_chk_guard inside of C function?

Tags: c

I have a function which changes the value of the stack check guard.
This function is compiled with `-fstack-protector-all`.
This means that stack check operations will be generated inside of this function. This added code will save the stack check value at the beginning into the stack and will check saved value at the end of the function. But we're changing the value. That is why, I expect stack smashing will be generated.

```
unsigned long __stack_chk_guard = 0;

void change___stack_chk_guard()
{
    __stack_chk_guard = 1234;
}

int main()
{
    change___stack_chk_guard();
    return 0;
}
```

So, can I do initialization of `__stack_chk_guard` like this?

Comment: Stack protector is now in thread local storage, not a single global.

Comment: @stark: It depends on target. To my knowledge it's only in TLS for x86[_64] and powerpc[64]. In particular ARM still uses the global.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to change the guard value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the formal answer in terms of the language as specified: **No**. The identifier `__stack_chk_guard` is in the reserved namespace, meaning that if you use it whatsoever, your program has undefined behavior. (Its being *reserved* is *precisely what makes it valid* for an implementation to use it in implementing a feature like stack protector.)

Second, the technical/mechanical answer: **No**, for targets that use the external identifier `__stack_chk_guard` as part of their stack protector implementation. The whole job of stack protector is to verify that the stack canary at the time of function return holds the same value that was stored to it at function entry, which comes (depending on target) from `__stack_chk_guard` or from an anonymous location in thread-local storage. If you change `__stack_chk_guard` during the lifetime of a funtion, the value at entry will necessarily differ from the value when the comparison is performed at return time, and stack protector will trigger and terminate the program just as if the stack had been smashed.

Likely the reason your test program is not crashing is that x86[_64] is a target that no longer uses `__stack_chk_guard`; instead it uses the more efficient TLS-based variant. If you're using gcc, you can compile with `-mstack-protector-guard=global` to get the obsolete behavior, and your program should crash as expected.

Comment: Are you sure if __stack_chk_guard is in a list of reserved?

Comment: @lollol: All identifiers beginning with two underscores or with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved in all contexts.

Comment: I think you're talking only for C++. For C it seems it is not a problem to use it, right?

Comment: @lollol: No, absolutely not. You cannot use identifiers beginning with `__` in C.

Comment: The relevant text is 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers, ¶1, bullet 1: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."